# Declare interface in TypeScript .d.ts file and consume from JavaScript file

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm using Visual Studio Code and would like to have intellisense hint when declaring my configuration variable as plain JavaScript object

*jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.js",
        "types/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

*types/index.d.ts*

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

declare var fooConfig: Foo;
```

*src/app.js*

```
const fooConfig = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 123
}
```

I expect when declaring using `const fooConfig` VS Code might offer intellisense about `a` and `b`, the current result I got complaint message about re-declaring the variable `fooConfig`.

P.S. I don't really know the possibility but I would like to have some intellisense so I can declare my configuration variable easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JSDoc syntax to describe types in JS files:

src/app.js

```
/** @type {Foo} */
const fooConfig = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 123
}
```

It works implicitly with d.ts files you have in your project, so there is no need to "include" them and there is no need to declare the var in the d.ts file.

Comment: Just to add - this page in the TS doc has further details:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

Answer (score -1):

Try `const fooConfig: Foo = {...}` in your JS file, after importing the interface. As it stands, TS is right you're declaring it twice.